# Direct access to @observable variable from other object

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Is it ok to access @observable variable directly from other object, without making it @published and defined as polymer element attribute?

For example, I have a custom element, defined without any data binding:

```
<my-element id="my"></my-element>
```

and, on response to some external event in it's parent element, I can do something like that:

```
($['my'] as MyElement).someObservableData = new MegaObject();
```

Looks like it working at first sight, but what I'm worring about, is that if anything can be broken after conversion with dart2js or minification if i wouldn't define polymer-element's attribute.

What is the best practice to do things like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is perfectly fine. When it's observable or published it's still a normal field of the class but is wrapped to fire events when the value changes.